# Extra Space when i add ListView inside a Frame layout

Tags: xamarin.forms

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGZHE.png)I am not clear what am I missing. Extra space at the bottom of the list. please check the screenshot attached below.

```
            <ListView ItemSelected="ListView_ItemSelected" VerticalOptions="Start" ItemsSource="{Binding RelayList}" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Gray" HasUnevenRows="True" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <Grid BackgroundColor="#E6E6E6" VerticalOptions="End">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Padding="10,10,10,0" VerticalOptions="Start">

                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Label Text="{Binding RelayName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                        <Label Text="{Binding RelayType}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small" />
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </StackLayout>
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="nextbtn.png" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" />


                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: I do not see any Screenshot!!!

Comment: I have missed it out.Now i have added it @G.hakim

Comment: You can chec k my answer below

Comment: @devhtml just make one row in grid with some specific height you want

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are using a Frame, A Frame has a default Padding of 20.

Which can be confirmed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.frame?view=xamarin-forms#remarks)

So now the there are two things you can do set the Padding to 0 in the Frame so you do not see this spacing(Can be done on L,T,R,B differently using the 4 parameters)

Or you can remove the Frame all together.

Comment: I have set frame padding 0 but still, I am facing the same issue